# Why PPPoE Connection fails with error 691 - ADSL2+ Modem

Tags: windows-7, networking, logging, modem, pppoe

On Windows 7, an ADSL2+ modem is used to connect to my ISP using a PPPoE connection.

1-Username and password are correct.

2-The modem is configured to accept bridge connection with my ISP VPI VCI ports.

When trying to connect with PPPoE, the authentication fails with an **error 691**

How to know the real reason that lets the authentication fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out;

windows logs the PPPoE connections to a file in **c:\windows\tracing\PPP.log**

When taking a deep look at this file it shows the reason **Account disabled** so it's ISP related.

But why the message is not displayed to the windows users ?